# MSDN - is it they or me?

Tags: c++, msdn, standard-library

In [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct1as7hw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) I cannot find header type_traits. Is it missing or I'm missing something (again...).

Comment: I will say that MSDN documents most things very well, but the documentation is clunky unless you know the exact name and use of the thing you're searching for. MSDN makes a good reference, but a very, VERY poor learning tool.

Comment: @San absolutely agree. I've came across good few examples from their site that were just very, very poor quality (style, programming practice etc.)

Comment: @San: Moreover, the number of clicks you have to perform to brows the documentation of member functions is just insanely high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because its here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx

It's an extension to the standard library.

Comment: and here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx. Why for the love of God? Why?

Comment: It's Microsoft! At least these links actually point somewhere - most links into microsoft.com end up at 'this page no longer exists!'

Answer (score 1):

That's a TR1 header.  I don't see any TR1 headers listed there.

Comment: VS2010 starts to implement the next C++ standard, where it is not tr1 anymore.